# Java Prime Number For Loop Failure

Tags: java, numbers

```
public class JavaP3 {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int n = 1; n < 1001; ++n) {
            boolean red = isPrime(n);
            if (red = true) {
                System.out.println("Prime #" + "\t" + n);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int num) {
        if (num == 1 || num == 2) {
            return true;
        }

        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i += 2) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This seems like it should run, as it is a very simple for loop. It is intended to print out all prime numbers between 1-1000, using the `isPrime` method. Is there something obvious I am missing, something wrong with the for loop, or something wrong with the placement of the main method?

Comment: Your for loop is missing `{}`.

Comment: This `if(red = true){` is assignment (not an equality test). Try `if(red == true){` **or** `if(red){`

Comment: `1` is not a prime. `=` is not `==` (and you don't need `==` anyway).

Comment: If you use a good IDE, e.g. Eclipse, it would warn you about issues (i.e. coding errors) like `if(red = true)`, and you wouldn't have to waste your own and everybody else's time on stuff like this. Good tools helps. A lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `true` to `red` with the `=` assignment operator.  The `==` operator compares for equality instead.  But because it's already a `boolean`, there is no need for a comparison.  Use:

```
if (red) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace = with == in the if condition
`if(red == true)`
or
`if(red)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 changes.

1) change if(red = true)  to  if(red)

Reason - if(red = true) will be always true and has no meaning

2) change
      for (int i=3; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i += 2)

```
      if (num % i == 0)

          return false;

  return true;
```

to

```
  for (int i=3; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i += 2)
  {

      if (num % i == 0)

          return false;
  }
  return true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested changes, but it's still not running. Do you have any other ideas by any chance?

Comment: Is it ok to use different logic instead of your logic for printing prime numbers?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure what's wrong with this particular logic.

Comment: i run your code it worked fine, did you applied both the changes? And what  is wrong in output after applying changes?

Comment: Netbeans won't produce any results. This whole thing may just be a problem with my IDE?

Comment: It's working now after I put it in a new library even though it was the only code in the previous one. Thanks again.